# Unstructuring a complex class with cattrs

Tags: python, json, datetime, python-attrs

I'm having problems using `attrs`/`cattrs` to transform a custom dataclass to JSON format. My class has the form:

```py
import attr
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Tuple, Set, Dict, FrozenSet

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class B:
    w: Set[datetime] = attr.ib()
    x: Set[str] = attr.ib()
    y: Set['A'] = attr.ib()
    z: Set[Tuple[datetime, str]] = attr.ib(factory=set)


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, cmp=False)
class A:
    a: str = attr.ib()
    b: FrozenSet[Team] = attr.ib()
    c: FrozenSet[Tuple[datetime, str]] = attr.ib(factory=frozenset)
    d: Dict[Tuple[str, str], float] = attr.ib(factory=dict)
```

The problem I face is that when I try to convert to a `dict` via `cattrs.unstructure`  and vice-versa via `cattrs.structure`, `cattrs` shows an error telling me that I should use a hook:

```py
import cattr

# Create instance of b
b_instance = B(...)
...
data = cattr.unstructure(b_instance)
print()
print(data)
print()
restored = cattr.structure(data, B)
assert b_instance == restored
```

```
ValueError: Unsupported type: <class 'datetime.datetime'>. Register a structure hook for it.
```

I registered a hook to transform the `datetime` to `str` with a given format:

```py
import cattr
from datetime import datetime

time_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
cattr.register_unstructure_hook(datetime, lambda dt: dt.strftime(time_format))
cattr.register_structure_hook(datetime, lambda s, _: datetime.strptime(s, time_format))
```

but then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime
```

I need to be able to transform from the object instance to JSON and back, using the datetime with the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Set type. If it exists in the type, then `cattr.unstructure` unable to serialize it. replace it with the Tuple and things going to work out:

```
from typing import Tuple, Set
from datetime import datetime

import cattr
import attr
import pytest


TIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
COMPLEX_TYPE = Tuple[Tuple[str, datetime]]
COMPLEX_TYPE_BAD = Set[Tuple[str, datetime]]

cattr.register_unstructure_hook(
    datetime, lambda dt: datetime.strftime(dt, format=TIME_FORMAT)
)
cattr.register_structure_hook(
    datetime, lambda dt_str, _: datetime.strptime(dt_str, TIME_FORMAT)
)


def test_cattrs_io_for_a():
    @attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
    class A:
        ds: datetime = attr.ib(factory=datetime.utcnow)

    a = A()
    a_ser = cattr.unstructure(a)
    a_des = cattr.structure(a_ser, A)
    assert isinstance(a_des, A)


def test_cattrs_io_for_b():
    @attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
    class B:
        ds: COMPLEX_TYPE = attr.ib(factory=set)

    b = B((("a", datetime.utcnow()), ("b", datetime.utcnow())))
    b_ser = cattr.unstructure(b)
    b_des = cattr.structure(b_ser, B)
    assert isinstance(b_des, B)


def test_cattrs_io_for_b_bad():
    @attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
    class B:
        ds: COMPLEX_TYPE_BAD = attr.ib(factory=set)

    b = B({("a", datetime.utcnow()), ("b", datetime.utcnow())})
    b_ser = cattr.unstructure(b)
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        b_des = cattr.structure(b_ser, B)
        assert isinstance(b_des, B)
```

It is looks like an issue in cattrs https://github.com/Tinche/cattrs/issues/48

Going to be fixed in the next release of the cattrs. Or you can build it from the `master` branch